# Excel IF statement regarding na

Tags: excel

In Excel, I entered "NA" in A1,
then in B1, I entered

```
=IF(A1>1,"True", "False")
```

then I got true. Is that because logically, NA does not belong to a number, so it simply passes the if test?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, changed my answer completly. After Doug Glancy noticed in comment and after I made some additional tests, I think you were right in the first place indeed. Seems like any text considered "larger" than any number.

Comment: then how do we compare strings? Is the defaulted always true?

Comment: How come if I put "1" in A1 and 1 in A2 `=A1=A2` yields FALSE?